# How to set default value of Boolean parameter false in SSRS?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix

I have 18 Boolean parameters in my report. I want to make their default value to false through expression when ever user runs the report.

I am trying this but its not working

```
=SIDIdNum.Value = "false"
```

Getting Error: parameter SIDIdNum caontain an error [BC30451]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you tried just...

```
false
```

[image]

I'm also not sure *where* you're trying to set this value?  If you are accessing the parameter from somewhere other than parameter properties dialog, you'll need to use

```
Parameters!SIDIdNum.Value="false"
```

Comment: I am trying to set from parameter properties. It worked Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

I had to tweak the prior answer in SSRS 2012.

I needed to make the value:  **=false**

Comment: Absolutely correct. Equal (=) sign is required in SSRS 2008 R2